Copied data not pasting at the cursor location second time
I have the following code where I am copying the following data:
ABC123
DEF123
HIJ123

and pasting it into the text area. So the cursor is just after the HIJ123 after pasting the code as shown below:

Now let’s say I introduce a new line after ABC123 as shown below:

And my cursor is on the line after ABC123 and then I try to past these 3 records again on that line, it is getting messed up as shown below:

Why it is not getting pasted where it should be and it's getting messed up ?


let element = document.getElementById("post-text");

element.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.clipboardData);
  element.value += (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text").trim()
});

document.getElementById('post-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var lines = $('#post-text').val().split('\n'); //gives all lines

  ///var lines = element.split('\n');//gives all lines

  //To paste
  /*
    ABC123
    DEF123
    HIJ123
 */

  console.log(lines);
  console.log(lines.length);
  var firstLine = lines[0];
  console.log(firstLine);
  var secondLine = lines[1];
  console.log(secondLine);

  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    $("#phrase").append("<div>" + lines[i] + "</div>")
  }
});
#case-stack p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;   /* <-- THIS PRESERVES THE LINE BREAKS */
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="post-text" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="What's up?" required></textarea><br>
<input type="button" id="post-button" value="Post!">
<div id="phrase"></div>



Reasoning behind the paste listner in my code:
The reason I had the paste listner is to avoid one issue. Whenever I am pasting copied text from an excel, after pasting it, it goes to the new line automatically. For example if I am pasting the selected content shown below :

and paste it in the text area, the new line cursor is always after HIJ123, on the next line. It doesn't happen if we are just copying the same data from the commented out code in my snippet but it does create this issue with Excel

You are appending the text to the existing value of the area: element.value += (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text").trim() so it will always be added to the end of the text (and not where the cursor's positioned)

You are also preventing the default behaviour (e.preventDefault();) and adding your own behaviour (element.value += (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text").trim()) - if you comment those two lines out, the code will behave as expected

Basically you are saying I should just get rid of this thing completely ? element.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {   e.preventDefault();   console.log(event.clipboardData);   element.value += (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text").trim() });

Yes, you can remove the entire 'paste' event listener (and let the default behaviour do its thing - see my answer below)

add event listener on paste


$('textarea').on('paste', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();//prevent pasted text being added
  // add ID so we can clear textarea
  let text_area_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + text_area_id).val('');
  let clip = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  let final_clip = clip.replace('', '\n');
  console.log(final_clip);
  $('#' + text_area_id).val(final_clip);
});




Can you share a full working example?

I don't think your code does what the OP is asking... it just keeps pasting the same text over and over (clearing and pasting again) - Did you even try this code?

You can just remove the entire 'paste' event listener and let the default behaviour do its thing.
See demo below


let element = document.getElementById("post-text");
/* removed paste listener */

document.getElementById('post-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var lines = $('#post-text').val().split('\n'); //gives all lines
  ///var lines = element.split('\n');//gives all lines

  //To paste
  /*
    ABC123
    DEF123
    HIJ123
 */

  console.log(lines);
  console.log(lines.length);
  var firstLine = lines[0];
  console.log(firstLine);
  var secondLine = lines[1];
  console.log(secondLine);

  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    $("#phrase").append("<div>" + lines[i] + "</div>")
  }
});
#case-stack p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* <-- THIS PRESERVES THE LINE BREAKS */
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="post-text" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="What's up?" required></textarea><br>
<input type="button" id="post-button" value="Post!">
<div id="phrase"></div>




Hmm. I think the reason I had the paste listner is to avoid one issue. Whenever I am pasting copied text from an excel, after pasting it, it goes to the new line automatically. For example if I am pasting it like this : https://i.sstatic.net/jt3VCn9F.png and paste it in the text area, the new line is always after HIJ123. It doesn't happen if we are just copying the same data from the commented out code in my snippet but it does creates this issue with excel.

Do you think there's a way to address this issue of not going to new line while copying and pasting stuff from and excel?
